# Shell method about y-axis for $y=\sqrt{x-1}$

Tags: calculus

Body:

$y=0$, $y=\sqrt{x-1}$, $y=2$ and $x=0$

The body is rotated around the y-axis, and i am supposed to find volume of the body with shell method.

My attempt:

$V=(\pi*1^2*2)+2\pi \int _1^5(x-1)(2-\sqrt{x-1})dx$

With gives $\frac{42\pi }{5}$ is this right?

Comment: almost...I think the (x-1) factor in your integral should just be x since the radius of your shell is still measured all the way to the y-axis

Comment: Are you sure? Since i splitted the body into 2 pieces, cylinder with radius 1 and second piece with i use shell method from 1 to 5. Is it possible to only use the shell method on this body?

Comment: This is similar to your question: https://study.com/academy/answer/use-the-method-of-cylindrical-shells-to-find-the-volume-of-the-solid-obtained-by-rotating-the-region-bounded-by-the-curves-y-sqrt-x-1-y-0-and-x-5-about-the-line-y-3.html

Comment: Yes. You can split it into a cylinder with radius 1 and use the shell method for the other part. But for that part, the radius of the shell is still x - 1, not x. You measure the radius all the way to the y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is  $$ A= 50 \pi -\int _1 ^5 2\pi x \sqrt {x-1} dx $$

Using my calculator, I have $A \approx 43.144$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you check if done the disk method right on the same body? My attempt: $V=\pi \cdot \int _0^2(y^2+1)^2dy$ and got the same volume, but i'm not sure if i done it right.

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct.